# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus - Finding derivative

Tags: calculus

If $$F(h(x))=\int_{0}^{h(x)}f(t)dt$$
Then
$$\frac{d}{dx}F(h(x))=f(h(x))h'(x)$$
How can I show that
$$\frac{d}{dx}F(h(x))=F'(h(x))h'(x)$$
I'm under the impression that the following isn't true: $$F'(h(x))=f(h(x))$$

Comment: If $F$ is a primitive of $f$, then the expression you don't believe to be trye is, actually, the definition of $F$ itself, so it is true.

Answer (score 1):

$F'(h(x))$ means "the function $F'$ evaluated at $h(x)$" so you have to plug in $h(x)$ to $F'$ but because $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$ you easily see that $F'(x) = f(x)$ and so $$F'(h(x)) = f(h(x))$$